# Diff Between numpy.random.exponential and random.expovariate

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

What is the difference between `numpy.random.exponential` and `random.expovariate`? I'm familiar with how random.exponential works.

Comment: The difference is that numpy.random.expovariate doesn't exist. If you're thinking of the [regular `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.expovariate), that's a completely different module.

Comment: My error. Yes, I'm thinking of random.expovariate.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean "What is the difference between [`numpy.random.exponential`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html) and [`random.expovariate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.expovariate)?"  The difference is that `random.expovariate` uses the "rate" or "inverse scale" as the parameter (corresponding to the parameter used in [the wikipedia article on the exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)), while `numpy.random.exponential` uses the scale as the parameter.  The parameters of the two versions are just inverses of each other.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. If I use 1/lambda for numpy.random.exponential and lambda for random.expovariate, the functions will behave similarly?

Comment: @jitsen try it out!

Comment: @jitsen Yes, they will draw samples from the same distribution.

Comment: Don't forget to click on the tick if this solves your problem

Comment: `random.expovariate` also seems to be faster than `numpy.random.exponential`

Comment: @Tropilio, for generating one or two variates, `random.expovariate` is faster.  For generating hundreds or thousands of variates,  numpy will be significantly faster, because it can do that in one functional call.